# facing problem while parsing .csv file

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I am parsing a .csv file with apex with below code.

```
String hex = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(objFile); 
        system.Debug('@@@hex '+ hex);
        final Integer bytesCount = hex.length() >> 1; 
        String[] bytes = new String[bytesCount]; 
        for(Integer i = 0; i < bytesCount; ++i){
            bytes[i] = hex.mid(i << 1, 2); 
        } 


       system.Debug('@@@bytes '+ bytes);
        csvAsString=EncodingUtil.urlDecode('%' + String.join(bytes, '%'), 'UTF-8');
```

At the first attempt it is working fine. But, If I update this .csv file, and saved it then I am facing problem. I have debug the code and here is my analysis.
 Log for first time (Working fine)

```
@@@bytes = (ef, bb, bf, 22, 46, 69, 72, 73, 74, 20, ...)
@@@csvAsString ﻿= "First Name","Last Name","LinkedIn Link","ID","Position","Company","Location","Industry","# of Connections"
```

Log for updated .csv file

```
@@@bytes = (46, 69, 72, 73, 74, 20, 4e, 61, 6d, 65, ...)
@@@csvAsString= First Name  Last Name   LinkedIn Link   ID  Position    Company Location    Industry    # of Connections
```

I guess that this is file format issue. Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks.
Regards,
Sandeep

Comment: Seems like encoding issue. UTF-8

Comment: Yes.. but why it is working at first time? I am using same method each time.

Comment: Previously it was Blob ,  now it is String. So format is changed.

Comment: Note that Excel CSV does not support UTF-8; Open Office does